# Closure compiler. Single/double quote optimization in JSF based page

Tags: javascript, jsf, compression, google-closure-compiler, yui-compressor

I try to minify `xhtml` pages with `htmlcompressor` (`javascript` compiler - **GCC** - google closure compiler).

GCC optimize quotes usage in strings. If in the string we use single quotes chars then GCC will conclude string in double quotes chars and vise versa. This is worked if we have completed `javascript` code at build project time, but not worked with `JSF`.

For example, can not figured out with the issue when we have `JSF` page with code

```
....
<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = "#{my.localized.bundle}"
</script>
....
```

Where `#{my.localized.bundle}` is `locali'zed message`.

If i will try to compress this example **NOT** on 'fly' but on build project time, then on client `javascript` code will be broken.

Resulting `javascript` code (with GCC quote optimizations and after render response `JSF` phase) will:

```
....
<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = 'locali'zed message'
</script>
....
```

Questions:

- GCC have options (flag) which allows disable such useless, for me, optimizations?
- Which compressor i can use to minify JSF based pages? (except YUI-compiler which also doing the quotes optimizations)

Comment: code in a script typed type="javascript/text" will never fire...

Answer (score 1):

You want your code to be escaped for use within string.  You can do this by using the output wrapper command-line options to specify as so:

```
--output_wrapper="%output|jsstring%"
```

Here you wouldn't be actually adding any wrapper text but simply taking advantage of the ability to specify that you want the output escaped for use in a string for embedding purposes.

Comment: I do not see option `output_wrapper` in list of available options https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/#Compressing_HTML_and_XML_files_from_a_command_line. Do not quite understand what you suggested to do. Could you tell more detail?

Comment: I can't help you there.